# Arranging summarized NAs in descending order after calculating them in each column in tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, na

I have a dataframe with 100+ columns. Many of them contain NAs. I want not only to calculate NAs in each column but also to arrange them in descending order.

Numbers in the second column are the numbers of NAs in each column.

```
Rows: 1
Columns: 5
$ EXT_SOURCE_1                 <int> 173378
$ EXT_SOURCE_2                 <int> 660
$ EXT_SOURCE_3                 <int> 60965
$ APARTMENTS_AVG               <int> 156061
$ BASEMENTAREA_AVG             <int> 179943
```

Using `df %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.)))) %>% glimpse()` does a perfect job, calculating NAs in each column and putting everything in two columns, but I cannot use `arrange(desc)`. Hence, it is tough to compare multiple columns.

Expected output:

```
Rows: 1
Columns: 5
$ BASEMENTAREA_AVG             <int> 179943
$ EXT_SOURCE_1                 <int> 173378
$ APARTMENTS_AVG               <int> 156061
$ EXT_SOURCE_3                 <int> 60965
$ EXT_SOURCE_2                 <int> 660
```

I tried to used `group_by()` and `summarise`, but it works for values, not NAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is caused by the summarise function returning a single column ("col_name : value") instead of two columns ("col_name" and "variable"). One potential solution is to use the pivot_longer() tidyverse function to split the output into two columns, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data(airquality)
dat1 <- airquality
dat1 %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.)))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "names", values_to = "values") %>% 
  arrange(desc(values))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   names   values
#>   <chr>    <int>
#> 1 Ozone       37
#> 2 Solar.R      7
#> 3 Wind         0
#> 4 Temp         0
#> 5 Month        0
#> 6 Day          0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for your time and efforts! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `colSums` and `is.na` to count number of `NA` values in each column, `sort` the result in decreasing order to get a named vector.

```
res <- sort(colSums(is.na(airquality)), decreasing = TRUE)
res

#  Ozone Solar.R    Wind    Temp   Month     Day 
#     37       7       0       0       0       0
```

If you need a dataframe `stack` it.

```
stack(res)

#  values     ind
#1     37   Ozone
#2      7 Solar.R
#3      0    Wind
#4      0    Temp
#5      0   Month
#6      0     Day
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for your time and efforts!